# Installing the lf file manager - lf command not found after installation

Tags: software-installation

I've just installed the lf file manager on my computer (Ubuntu 22.04.2) by typing the following command in my terminal, as indicated on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf):

```
env CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -ldflags="-s -w" github.com/gokcehan/lf@latest
```

(I first had to install the go compiler and language using `sudo apt install golang-go`. Without this the terminal displayed the message `env: ‘go’: No such file or directory`.)

According to the same [GitHub page](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf),

> After the installation lf command should start the application in the current directory.

However, running either of `lf`, `lf --help` or `lf --version` displays

```
lf: command not found
```

Have I missed a step in the installation? Any suggestions to fix this?
I apologise if this is a silly question - I am a complete beginner in Linux. :)

Comment: Why not just `apt install lf`?

Comment: @FedKad when I type `sudo apt install lf` it says `E: Unable to locate package lf` :(

Comment: Sorry. It seems it is `apt install lfm` in 22.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/lfm

Comment: @FedKad Thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: `lfm` is not the same as `lf`, but i might actually use this too haha

Answer (score 0):

`go install` places the executable into the $GOPATH/bin directory,
So to make it work you must add $GOPATH/bin to your PATH variable.
To do that you can simply add this line to your ~/.bashrc file

```
export PATH="$(go env GOPATH)/bin:$PATH"
```